# Two commands in one

Tags: command-line, editor, sh

Normally, I'll create a `.sh` file in using `touch file.sh` and then modify the script with the editor in using `sudo emacs file.sh`. Is there exist a way of doing this in the same time? I mean after create the `.sh`  file, then editor open right after.

Comment: command `sudo emacs file.sh` will create file.sh as well as opens it in editor. Is this you looking for?

Comment: @heemayl What's wrong with the accepted question. I tried with `emacs` and nano, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity Only if you save the content, have a test like mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/a/852739/216503

Comment: Yes, but this is what I looked for.

Comment: You do understand that _command sudo emacs file.sh will create file.sh as well as opens it in editor_ -- is completely wrong?

Comment: Heemayl is correct. OP should ask " how can I edit a new file without 'touching' it first" or something akin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo emacs file.sh` does not create a file on the filesystem (at first).

`emacs` opens and works on a buffer, so unless you save in the usual manner like `C-s` is `emacs`, the file won't be saved on the filesystem. After opening buffer with `sudo emacs file.sh` (given the file does not exist already), if you close the buffer by `C-x-c` the file won't be saved/created.

Note that, for creating an empty file, one way would be to leverage shell redirection with a dummy input (e.g. `true` (`:`)), `bash` even supports empty redirection:

```
: >file.sh
>file.sh ## In bash
```

Note that, this will truncate `file.sh` if it exists already, to prevent that you can set the `noclobber` option which will prevent the truncation if the file exists already:

```
set -o noclobber
```

Answer (score 3):

Command `sudo emacs file.sh` will open `file.sh` in buffer. `file.sh` will only be created if content is saved using `C-s`  if file doesn't exist already.

You can also use any other text editor like `nano`, `vim` or `gedit` as `sudo nano file.sh`.

Comment: Definitely an improvement on the original post.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo touch file.sh && sudo emacs file.sh`

The `&&` strings the commands together, performing the first and then the second [provided the first command succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of).